# C# AutoCAD Plugin SQLite - Error Table not found on rare occasions

Tags: c#, sqlite, path, relative-path, autocad

I am creating a plugin for AutoCAD which uses an external Database(SQLite).
and on rare occasions i am getting the "table not found" error. Its driving me crazy. I have seen plenty of forums for answers could not find a solution.

it is working on most cases only few instances it throwing this error.

How do I solve this issue.

I am using relative path to the DB and it lies within the Debug/ release folder.

What is the best approach to attach a db to a application (in my case its a .dll not exe)

---

thanks guys for reply...Sorry I didnt get any email notification...

**Here is the information you requested.**

I have a seperate class-which handles connections.
here is how i I connect to the DB.

```
    public static SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string conn_string = string.Format("Data Source=./sdf_db1.s3db");
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(conn_string);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists("./sdf_db1.s3db"))
        {
            Global.variables.mess_out_exception("Missing Database file", "Error");
        }

        return conn;

    }
```

Since this is a plugin for AutoCAD Civil3D it resides in the Appdata\autodesk folder to load on start-up. Everything about the app is working great except rarely I get the table not found error..looks like may be the relative path cannot resolve quickly when the application is started.

I have difficulty finding the absolute path if I tried to use "Application.ExecutablePath;" and few other things which I find online..all I get is the location of Acad.exe not the location of the plugin.

1. How do I get the absolute path of the location of the plugin to get the location of the DB(since the DB and .dll lies in the same folder).
2. How do I use both absolute and relative path in the connection string (so if the relative path fails the code can try to locate the db using the absolute path).

Any other suggestion would be great. Thanks

---

I Found the cause for the issue,
When I run the application and close the application correctly (Means after completing all the process) it works fine I dont get any error message...

### I get the error only when I close the window of the application in between. Looks like the connection opened for the DB is still busy if I try to run the application.

Comment: How exactly are you using the relative path? Show the code!

Comment: show the piece of code where you are getting error..are you using an app.config file?

Answer (score 1):

Get the path of the plugin with

```
var asmpath = Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location );
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not take an alternate route?

Instead of trying to find your DLL and associated SQLite database, I would recommend that you install them in a specific location. This way you can easily package it with an installer.

You can utilize automatic loading of .NET modules through AutoCAD with registry keys:
http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/09/automatic_loadi.html

With this, you can simply install your AutoCAD plugins as if they were a normal program, and get AutoCAD to load them for you on launch.

Comment: thanks Origin I think this what I am going to use for final deployment. Just a quick question. when the setup deploys my plugin it goes in to the default Appdata folder autodesk. how do i get the users's app data folder using .net

Comment: I usually have my plugins install to something like `C:\CadUtils`. If you really wanted to install to the user's `AppData` directory, you could access the environment variable (`%APPDATA%` at the command prompt) to find it.